# Rails Meta Tags, undefined method `set_meta_tags' in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, meta-tags

Using the gem [Meta Tags](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags)

The [documentation](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags#using-metatags-in-controller) states to put this in the controller:

```
set_meta_tags :title => 'Member Login',
              :description => 'Member login page.',
              :keywords => 'Site, Login, Members'
```

But, thats what I did, not sure if I need to have something wrapped around it:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to main_app.root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end   
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  before_filter :configure_devise_params, if: :devise_controller?

  set_meta_tags :og => {
                    :title    => 'The Rock',
                    :type     => 'video.movie',
                    :url      => 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/',
                    :image    => 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg',
                    :video    => {
                      :director => 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000881/',
                      :writer   => ['http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0918711/', 'http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0177018/']
                    }
                  }
end
```

Then in my view:

```
<%= display_meta_tags %>
```

But I'm getting the error `undefined method 'set_meta_tags'`

Comment: If you are using that from controller then atleast define it in an `action`, you will never get something without a method. Or else use them in views.

Comment: @Deep Hello! So lets say that I want this meta tag to be used across all pages, we just put it in an action, but it wouldn't work if we call that action right? How do I call that action? I think there's a before method? but I'm not sure exactly what it is... or maybe I'm thinking this wrong? Maybe put it in the `before_filter :some_action` ?

Comment: @Deep Just tried the `before_filter`, but getting error: `stack level too deep`

Comment: So why not use in layout?

Answer (score -1):

I usually place it in the application controller to keep the view tidy.

```rb
# app/config/application.rb

# ...

before_action :please_set_meta_tags

def please_set_meta_tags
  set_meta_tags title:       'website name',
                description: 'website description',
                og: {
                  title:     'website name',
                  type:      'website',
                  url:       request.original_url,
                  image:     { _: view_context.image_url('myimage1.jpg'), width: 1200, height: 630 },
                             { _: view_context.image_url('myimage2.jpg'), width: 1200, height: 630 }
                }
end
# ...
```

```rb
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

...
<head>
  <%= display_meta_tags %>
  ...
```

I use `view_context.image_url()` instead of `image_url()` to get the image as I'm not in a view (therefore `view_context` is needed).

And remember to **restart the server once you installed the gem**! (it might be so obvious that you forget it)